# Tensorflow inference too slow when loading multiple models

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, object-detection-api

I finetuned two Mobilenet models on diferent datasets based on the tensorflow object_detection API example from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb). When I use eager mode (tf.executing_eagerly() is True) using only one model then the inference runs at 0.036 seconds per image. When I load two models Keras required to convert to graph mode (tf.executing_eagerly() is False) and the inference runs at 1.8 seconds per image. What I'm doing wrong?

```
def inference(pipeline_config, checkpoint_path):

  print('Building model and restoring weights', flush=True)
  num_classes = 3

  # Load pipeline config and build a detection model.
  configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)
  model_config = configs['model']
  model_config.ssd.num_classes = num_classes

  detection_model = model_builder.build(
  model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

  ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)

  ckpt.restore(checkpoint_path).expect_partial()

  # Run model through a dummy image so that variables are created
  image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(tf.zeros([1, 320, 320, 3]))
  prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
  _ = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
  print('Weights restored!')

  return detection_model

def get_model_detection_function(detection_model):
  """Get a tf.function for detection."""

  # Again, uncomment this decorator if you want to run inference eagerly
  @tf.function
  def detect(input_tensor):
    """Run detection on an input image.

    Args:
    input_tensor: A [1, height, width, 3] Tensor of type tf.float32.
      Note that height and width can be anything since the image will be
    immediately resized according to the needs of the model within this
    function. 

    Returns:
      A dict containing 3 Tensors (`detection_boxes`, `detection_classes`,
      and `detection_scores`).
    """
    preprocessed_image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(input_tensor)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(preprocessed_image, shapes)
    return detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)

  return detect


def mainProcess():
  
  print('Loading model 1...') 
  g1 = tf.Graph()
  s1 = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=g1)
  with g1.as_default(), s1.as_default():
    detection_model_1 = inference('config_1/pipeline.config', 'Checkpoint_1/ckpt-1')
    detect_fn_1 = get_model_detection_function(detection_model_1)
    s1.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())


  print('Loading model 2...') 
  g2 = tf.Graph()
  s2 = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=g2)
  with g2.as_default():
    detection_model_2  = inference('config_2/pipeline.config', 'Checkpoint_2/ckpt-1')
    detect_fn_2 = get_model_detection_function(detection_model_2)
    s2.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

  for i, f in enumerate(listdir('images_dir/')):
    ...
    ... read the image
    ...
    with g1.as_default():
      with s1.as_default():
        sec = time.time()
        input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_img, dtype=tf.float32)
        detections = detect_fn_1(input_tensor)
        detections = s1.run(detections)
        curr = time.time()
        print("Finished iterating in: " + str(curr - sec) + " seconds")

    # the same for detection_model_2
```

For eager mode with only one model the mainProcess is:

```
def mainProcess():
  
  print('Loading model...') 
  detection_model_1 = inference('config_1/pipeline.config', 'Checkpoint_1/ckpt-1')
  detect_fn_1 = get_model_detection_function(detection_model_1)

  for i, f in enumerate(listdir('images_dir/')):
    ...
    ... read the image
    ...
    sec = time.time()
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_img, dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn_1(input_tensor)
    print(detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy())
    print(detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy())
    curr = time.time()
    print("Finished iterating in: " + str(curr - sec) + " seconds")
```